# Get posts between custom dates

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, post-meta, meta-query

I created an `event` CPT and a meta box with a date. I saved the date as `post_meta` in the form `dd.mm.yyyy`.

Now I want to create a shortcode that queries all posts which's dates meet the condition (e.g.)

```
(01.05.2013 <= {event_date} <= 21.08.2013)
```

I could convert the strings into Date objects or whatever. But I don't even have a slight approach how to query in comparison of custom `meta_values`.

Can you think of a good point to start off? Or would I need a complete different approach?

**EDIT**

I suddenly found something (maybe I got the right google-ideas). What I read suggested to save the dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` form. So I came up with the query:

```
query_posts(array('meta_query' => array(array('meta_key' => 'ows_schedule_field-date', 'meta_value' => '2013-08-15', 'type' => 'date', 'compare' => '=='))));
```

I got one post with exact this date. But unfortunately the query returns some random other post which didn't even has this meta.

**EDIT 2**

I also tried this one without success...

```
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'schedule_event', 'meta_key' => 'ows_schedule_field-date', 'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'ows_schedule_field-date', 'value' => '2013-08-15', 'type' => 'date', 'compare' => '>='))));
```

When I use `get_post_meta(285, 'ows_schedule_event-date', true);` (285 is one of the posts) I get `2013-08-15`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you *have to* store your dates in a form that sorts properly mathematically. Unix timestamps will do that. The only human-like calendar format that does it is `YYYY-MM-DD`. You have your dates saved backwards. 
Assuming you store as `YYYY-MM-DD`, then this should work:

```
$args = array(
  'meta_query' => array(
     array(
        'meta_key' => 'ows_schedule_field-date', 
        'meta_value' => array($date_one,$date_two), // both dates YYYY-MM-DD
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
     )
   )
)
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. When I use `meta_key` and `meta_value`, the query returns a single post that doesn't even have this meta! When using `key` and `value` (like in lots of posts on the net) it returns nothing. And also limiting the post_type results in emptiness

Comment: I already converted to `yyyy-mm-dd` and working with this format now.

Comment: I will look into it later.